# How to do Gayatri sandhya Upasana?

Tags: gayatri-mantra, sandhyavandanam, gayatri-upasana

The book ‘om Gayatri and sadhana’ written by swami mukhyananda of Ramakrishna mission has discussed 24 practices to perform the Sandhya Upasana . These are acamanam, vignesvara dhyanam, pranayama ,Sankalpa ,marjanam ,prasanam, punarmarjanam ,arghya pradanam ,prayaschittarghyam, aikyanusandhanam, deva tarpanam, japasankalpah, Pranava japa, Gayatri-avahanam, gayatri Japah, Gayatri upasthanam, suryoprashthanam ,samastyabhivadanam, digdevata-vandanam, Yama vandanam, Harihara vandanam, Suryanarayana vandanam, samarpanam, Raksha. I am , however confused about the procedure to conduct and whether all of the practices have to be conducted to get the fruitful result?